# ToList Method not Found when using AutoMapper with Xamarin Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper's projection method with Xamarin Sqlite.  My code looks like:

```
var myList = conn.Table<SomeTable>()
    .Where(w => w.ForeignKeyId == foreignKeyId)
    .AsQueryable()
    .ProjectTo<SomeTableDto>()
    .ToList();
```

The code works on the Android emulator but fails on the iOS emulator.  The error on iOS is:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

The top of the stack trace is below.  If need be I can supply the full stack trace, it's quite long.

```
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileMemberInitExpression     (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x00000] in     /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1532  
at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileNoLabelPush (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x002a7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3539/f37444ae/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1660
```

The method not found is the ToList() call.  Why would the method not be found on iOS?

I've fixed the problem by doing the below but I'm curious why my initial code didn't work on iOS.

```
var someTableList = conn.Table<SomeTable>()
    .Where(w => w.ForeignKeyId == foreignKeyId)
    .ToList();

var myDtoList = Mapper.Map<List<SomeTableDto>>(someTableList);
```

I'm using AutoMapper 5.1.1, Xamarin Forms 2.3.1, and Sqlite-net-pcl 1.1.2.

Comment: Did you add the Nuget packages to your Forms PCL *and* the iOS project? They are needed in both.

Comment: I've only added AutoMapper my PCL project and it's not added to either the droid or iOS projects.  When I go to add AutoMapper to iOS is lists over 30 dependencies it also needs to install so I'm hesitant to do that.  The example code I listed above is all in my PCL project.

Comment: There's the problem. The packages must be added to the native projects. I don't know how and why that would introduce 30 dependencies.

Comment: @Krumelur, I have other database methods in my PCL project that use AutoMapper and they work.  It's just the ProjectTo and ToList that are giving me problems and only in iOS.  The code in my question works fine on Andriod and I didn't include AutoMapper in Andorid project.

Comment: Well, you _could just give it a try_, right? It might be the linker that strips things out on iOS. If you are refusing to _try_ things, you'll never know.

Comment: @Krumelur Thank you for your suggestion. I tried adding AutoMapper to the iOS project nothing changed.  I still get the same error.  You got me thinking about the iOS linker.  That could be problem but I'm not sure how to test that.

Comment: Another possibility might be that you pulled in dependencies on .Net Core by accident or via some Nuget package. But unfortunately, I don't know how to help here. I haven't played with .Net Core yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is the iOS linker.  I found similar issues at:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1542

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/686

Thanks for @Krumelur for pointing me in the direction of the iOS linker.  If anyone can think of anything else please let me know.